# Generating a connection of researchers graph out of DBLP

Tags: networking

I'd like to know the connection of researchers. Similar to the connection of LinkedIn. In the field of computer science, the [DBLP database](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/) seems to be useful. Does anyone know a tool to generate a FoaF graph out of DBLP data and a FoaF (Friend of a Friend) graph rendering tool?

Comment: There are many possibilities to generate a graph. E.g. parse it with Python and then use http://gephi.org to visualize it or e.g. in http://flowingdata.com/2012/08/02/how-to-make-an-interactive-network-visualization/. However, most likely you won't be able to visualize all at once, but rather - e.g. a graph for a given person.

Comment: Currently, I'm looking for a ready-to-run-solution instead of coding it for myself :)

Comment: I think [ArnetMiner](http://arnetminer.org/) is already generating the social graph for researchers. EDIT: You can actually download the FOAF graph directly from anyone's profile, and you can look at the graph at http://arnetminer.org/association-home

Comment: If there is a need, I can write one :). See https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki and I want to play a bit with D3.js. But... not this week.

Comment: [Microsoft Academic Search](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/) can do it too. Search for the first author, klick on it's name (orange background), click "Geanology Graph", Click "Co-author Graph", enter the name of the other person on the right and press enter.

Comment: @koppor: So what exactly do you want? You can get the FOAF for any researcher from ArnetMiner, such that each connection is referenced by its ArnetMiner profile, where the FOAF can be obtained. Do you know need more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Microsoft Academic Research](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/) can do something similar for you, you just need to have Sliverlight plugin installed in your browser. Search for the first author, click on it's name (orange background), click "Geanology Graph", Click "Co-author Graph", enter the name of the other person on the right and press enter.

Comment: Did the graph visualization move someplace else?

Answer (score 4):

A bachelor thesis of interest for you:

Remo Lemma, Ebony - Visualizing the DBLP Database. University of Lugano, 2010

url : http://www.inf.usi.ch/faculty/lanza/Downloads/Lemm2010a.pdf